# In Domain-Driven Design, how to determine if sending an email is an application level or domain level concern?

Tags: php, email, events, domain-driven-design

Suppose you have a simple application called "Next in Line". Any business who has long waiting lines may want your software to give customers a better line queue experience.

Stakeholder says "**When** a customer wants a ticket, they walk up to our computer console and enter their email address. Then they will receive an email that contains their ticket number and unique access login to our app for more ticket queue features". Sending the email with the ticket number (and access to the app) is integral to the business.

Our Command Handler (application level) may look like this:

```
class TakeTicketCommandHandler
{
   private $repo;

   public function __construct(TicketRepository $repo)
   {
       $this->repo = $repo;
   }

   public function handle(TakeTicketCommand $command) 
   {
      $ticket = new Ticket(new EmailValueObject($command->getEmail()));

      DB::transaction(function () {
           // Send email here from the command handler? 
           // Seems domain "leaky" because Ticket Aggregate Root is responsible for this?
           ...

           $this->repo->persist($ticket);
      }
   }
}
```

Our Ticket Aggregate Root may look like this:

```
class Ticket extends AggregateRoot
{
    private $id;
    private $email;

    public function __construct(EmailValueObject $email)
    {
        $this->id = new GUID();
        $this->email = $email;

        // Maybe some more domain logic here
        ...

        // Send email here?
        // Should I have injected an interface for sending an email here?
        ...
    }        

}
```

**Questions:**

1. How should the email requirement from stakeholder be implemented in a Domain-Driven Design app? (use code above to demonstrate how you would do it and explain why). How do we know when something is an application level requirement versus a domain level requirement?
2. Notice the email is in a transaction, however transactions rollback for persistence here and not services like emailing. If the ticket persistance fails, what can we do about the email? (Should we provide an undo action like sending out another email informing user of the error?)
3. Say we want to have Ticket also raise an event like `TicketQueuedEvent`. In the event handler for this event, another Aggegrate Root is updated. Is this bad practice/modelling? If the application level services are meant to orchestrate the domain, then is Aggregate Root to Root communication through Events a valid approach to DDD?

Comment: As far as I can tell sending an email is an infrastructure responsibility and has nothing to do with the domain. It can be a reaction on a domain event for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the 3 specific questions, I will try and answer 1 and 2 as best I can, and treat 3 a little separate.
It is the responsibility of the Domain to solve all the business requirements. Having to send an e-mail is part of this business requirement, therefore the responsibility of the domain.

The problem is that we require some external component to perform the sending of the mail, which we clearly do not want to muddle our domain.

**Firstly, the issue of the Transaction**:

As you mentioned, it could rollback (or forward / commit).
The entire operation should be handled as one unit of work. So everything should fail or pass as one operation, including the e-mail.
Generally, you want your application to respond to the users' request asap, and not have him wait while some e-mail server is sending the email. So we tend to write an entry (think along the lines of CQRS commands) that specifies all the details of the e-mail, and we process that from a separate worker job that runs every 10 seconds or so.

**The responsibility or where the logic should be:**

There are a couple of ways to solve this.

1.

I generally let the domain know about an interface of `INotifyService` which knows nothing about the implementations of notifying the customer. I do the implementation with adapter pattern which can take communication adapters of say: Sms, Email etc. This way when implementations are added, or customer has an option of opting in for specific communication methods, we can simply use the required adapters, and the calling code remains unchanged.
I suggest using that INotifyService in your domain via a double-dispatch as it keeps your domain entity cleaner.

2.

Another option is having an Application Service layer that handles the sending explicitly after the domain operation is completed.
The issue is that your logic is now a side-car to your domain logic, and every time that domain operation is performed, and you need to send an e-mail, you have to remember to call the method. Similarly to the previous domain focused solution, you need a unit of work that is controlled for the duration of that "Atomic Unit Of Work".
This is normally quite easy when you have a web-application. You can read more about Application Service Layer: 
[Fowler - Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html)
Hope that helps a bit.

**Should you use a Notify mechanism**

So this is for Question3.

That would be entirely up to you.
I have found that not raising events and reacting to them can sometimes be hard to track. It becomes a bit harder to know the execution sequence of the code if you do not know how the system is put together.

Admittedly over time you get used to it, and it can be made to work.

Hope all this makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

> Example which you show don't have business logic and following DDD in this example will overcomplicate you code.

How should the email requirement from stakeholder be implemented in a Domain-Driven Design app?

> By publishing event and subscribe to this email by email
>   infrastructure service.

How do we know when something is an application level requirement versus a domain level requirement?

> Domain - business logic.
>   Infrastructure - abstract technical concerns (db, email). 
>   Application - transactions, high-level logging and security.

Notice the email is in a transaction, however transactions rollback for persistence here and not services like emailing. If the ticket persistance fails, what can we do about the email? (Should we provide an undo action like sending out another email informing user of the error?)

> If business ask to notify client you can create emailErorEvent if not just do error logging on application level.

Say we want to have Ticket also raise an event like TicketQueuedEvent. In the event handler for this event, another Aggegrate Root is updated. Is this bad practice/modelling? If the application level services are meant to orchestrate the domain, then is Aggregate Root to Root communication through Events a valid approach to DDD?

> sending events it is valid approach. Consistency between roots can
>   be a problem. You should not have operations that use
>   aggregates and have to be consistent.

Hope it helps.